How to train a keras model with a single output using two different metrics with different target values
The question is complete in the title. For the context, I am training an alignment model using a CTC loss. Note, that the CTC loss requires as target value the sequence of labels (the main point for using a CTC loss is that one does not need a label annotation of the sequence of observations). Additionally, for research purposes, I'd like to use a metric that evaluates the probability distribution of the model using the label annotations of the observations. This is generally not required but is used here to study model behavior.
More formally, if the sequence of observations has length N, then the output distribution O produced by the model will also have length N. If S is the label sequence without repetitions, e.g. S=A,B,A, ... with duration L, and D is the label sequence annotation of the observations -D=A,A,B,B,B,A,A,A,... then D also has length N. In that situation, the CTCloss uses inputs CTC_loss(S,O), while the categorical_crossentropy would use CC_loss(D,O).
So the model has one output but the metric and loss function require different target values.
I've seen this question and answer but in the present case, the two target tensors have different dimensions. It appears quite unfortunate to establish a complex aggregation and splitting method, here note as well that the duration extended label sequence should not be used by the loss function employed for training.
It would be possible to duplicate the model's output, but then one would have to add zero weight to the CC_loss during training because the CC_loss should not be used.
For the moment, I imagine overwriting train_step and test_step, but I would prefer a simpler approach. The documentation of the loss and metric matching looks rather brief. I wonder whether the dict based approach using output names might help.

This isn't clear. When I hear two different target values, why not have two outputs. Then each output has it's associated loss function.

Thanks for the question @matt. I enhanced the description. Hopefully, it is more clear.
